# RegEx Adding Strings to a List

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, list, visual-studio-2012

If I know the start of a string, and the end of a string (that occurs many times in a large string), what is the best way to get the contents between the two strings and add this contents to a List of String?

Is RegEx the best way to do this? If so, can I please have some example code to work with?

**EDIT**

I am using Visual Basic.net and this question is in relation to getting the files in a project by opening up the .vbproj file and getting the information.

Here is an example:

```
<Compile Include="CommonActions.vb" />
<Compile Include="Controller.vb" />
<Compile Include="formAbout.designer.vb">
  <DependentUpon>formAbout.vb</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="formAbout.vb">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="FormKey.designer.vb">
  <DependentUpon>FormKey.vb</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="FormKey.vb">
  <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
```

I am wanting to get a list of the .vb files. In the above example, the list will contain the following:

CommonActions.vb,Controller.vb,formAbout.designer.vb,formAbout.vb,FormKey.designer.vb,FormKey.vb

Comment: may i know what is input and what is output of your requirement. give some examples. Of-course we can do it with regex but  it changes based on requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In c#

`var matches = Regex.Match("Your_regex_pattern")`

will return you collection of all matches.

See also for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx

Add ot to list in your favorit way. For example -

`yourList = matches. Select(m=> m.Value).ToList();`